# Do we need CRC check while downloading file from server in esp8266 nodeMCU using arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, crc, nodemcu, ota

I want to download a bin file from server for OTA process. But **how I can download the whole file without any error**. I am using esp8266 on Arduino IDE core. For OTA, I am using **updater class of esp8266** core library. Is it good to use **error checking method like CRC** check? If yes how I can implement it?

Thanks!

- IDE: Arduino IDE
- Board: NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP8266)

Comment: Network transfer does some error checking already. 
Do you verify the file content after writing it to the NodeMCU memory? 
If you are *really* concerned, you might consider this as well ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should checksum or hash the image and verify it before trusting it. ESP8266 library has built-in MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 implementations that would be good for this.

The ArduinoOTA class implementation bundled with ESP8266 uses MD5 or SHA256 for validation.

- [MD5 library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/MD5Builder.cpp)
- [SHA1 library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/da6ec83b5fdbd5b02f04cf143dcf8e158a8cfd36/libraries/Hash/examples/sha1/sha1.ino)
- [ESP8266 ArduinoOTA library](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ota_updates/readme.html#basic-security)

I need to implement a similar OTA tool. I'll try to report back later when I have actually done it.